# Can 3% hydrogen peroxide be used as effective disinfectant and antiseptic?

Tags: bacteriology, virology, hygiene

I was curious to see whether 3% hydrogen peroxide can be used as antimicrobial and virucidal product for daily use in home. There are  several disinfecting products in the market claim that use of these wipes for some minutes can disinfect the hard surface. Also, there are quite a few ethyl alcohol based hand sanitizers. Can 3% hydrogen peroxide be used as effective disinfectant and antiseptic - similar efficacy with those of the commercial disinfecting products?

Website https://www.cdc.gov/hicpac/Disinfection_Sterilization/7_0formaldehyde.html discuss use of hydrogen peroxide against a wide range of pathogens. I found that the bottle of 3% hydrogen peroxide lists it as  [antiseptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiseptic) - to use for gargle etc. Can 3% hydrogen peroxide be used as a disinfectant for a broad spectrum of microbes?

Comment: Nope. Some microbes express high levels of [catalase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalase), in which case 3% HOOH does nothing to them.

Comment: If you need to disinfect regularly for medical reasons, it would be best to consult with your medical doctor. If there is no specific medical reason, and you are not particularly exposed to pathogens, the information of the "center of disease control and prevention", of the US government, which you refer to (and contains a detailed answer to your question) is more trustworthy than companies that have large budgets for advertisement to pull the money out of your pockets, with sub-perfect products, and with scaring people. If you are exposed to pathogens at work, consult your bio-safety officer.